# Extra test run when using InlineAutoData without using InlineAutoData

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, autofixture

I have the challenge that when using `InlineAutoData` that the test is run with random values as well. The background is that I am testing a conversion with some input that is required to follow the specification. I am not interested in random data.

The following test runs twice. Once with the `InlineAutoData` and one with random strings. The test have been deliberately made simple and to fail on the random data run:

```
[Theory, GeneralTransferTestConventions]
[InlineAutoData("Allowed", "Allowed")]
public void Testing(string test1Data, string test2Data)
{
    Assert.Equal(test1Data, test2Data);
}
```

My question is if there is a way to avoid the test run with random data and how to do that?

Comment: `GeneralTransferTestConvention` **isa** `AutoDataAttribute` - i.e. it defines a ow of the rowtest. The 'conventions' do not establish any per-run state - i.e. you need to have a `CompositeAutoData` in there to mix supplying data with applying conventions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the AutoFixture stuff integration:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("Allowed", "Allowed")]
public void Testing(string test1Data, string test2Data)
{
    Assert.Equal(test1Data, test2Data);
}
```

This is a pure xUnit.net test, and is entirely deterministic.

As a note, though, there's no reason to make a test parametrised if there's only going to be a single set of test cases, so either add more `InlineData` test cases:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("Allowed", "Allowed")]
[InlineData("foo", "foo")]
[InlineData("bar", "bar")]
public void Testing(string test1Data, string test2Data)
{
    Assert.Equal(test1Data, test2Data);
}
```

or make it a 'normal' test:

```
[Fact]
public void Testing()
{
    var test1Data = "Allowed";
    var test2Data = "Allowed";
    Assert.Equal(test1Data, test2Data);
}
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that solution. (sorry about micro comment)
Aside from needing to use `[InlineAutoData("Allowed", "Allowed")]` as `[InlineData("Allowed", "Allowed")]` somehow makes the test not visible in the Visual Studio test runner I am using.

Comment: If `[InlineData]` doesn't work with your test runner, I'd think that's a defect in the test runner, but if that's the case, I'd be surprised if `[InlineAutoData]` works.